# Spring Websockets STOMP - get client IP address

Tags: stomp, spring-websocket

Is there any way to obtain STOMP client IP address? I am intercepting inbound channel but I cannot see any way to check the ip address.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I see that it would possible to get that IP address from WebSocketSession...

Answer (score 18):

You could set the client IP as a WebSocket session attribute during the handshake with a `HandshakeInterceptor`:

```
public class IpHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {

    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response,
            WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {

        // Set ip attribute to WebSocket session
        attributes.put("ip", request.getRemoteAddress());

        return true;
    }

    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response,
            WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception exception) {          
    }
}
```

Configure your endpoint with the handshake interceptor:

```
@Override
protected void configureStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").addInterceptors(new IpHandshakeInterceptor()).withSockJS();
}
```

And get the attribute in your handler method with a header accessor:

```
@MessageMapping("/destination")
public void handlerMethod(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor ha) {
    String ip = (String) ha.getSessionAttributes().get("ip");
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is possible to get this attribute in service without passing SimpMessageHeaderAccessor ? I mean something similiar to injecting HttpServletRequest

Comment: Always getting ip as 127.0.0.1.How to get remote client's  ip?

Comment: It is genius! :) And thank you for the deep answer with details of integration. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

Below example updated to get the exact remote client ip:

```
@Component
public class IpHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {

   @Override
   public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response,
                               WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
    // Set ip attribute to WebSocket session
    if (request instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest) {
        ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = (ServletServerHttpRequest) request;
        String ipAddress = servletRequest.getServletRequest().getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
        if (ipAddress == null) {
            ipAddress = servletRequest.getServletRequest().getRemoteAddr();
        }
        attributes.put("ip", ipAddress);
    }
    return true;
}

   public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response,
                           WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception exception) {
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like your application is behind the reverse proxy and that is why you have to get the "X-FORWARDED-FOR" header.
More information here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

So it feels like your statement "Below example updated to get the exact remote client ip" is actually for NOT TYPICAL situation as you have assumed when you wrote your answer, but for more specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to add this information as a comment, but stackoverflow complains that it is too long for the comment, so I post it as answer to

> It is possible to get this attribute in service without passing
> SimpMessageHeaderAccessor ? I mean something similiar to injecting
> HttpServletRequest – shark Nov 23 '15 at 15:02

question.

I was able to achieve "close" results with such syntax:

```
@MessageMapping("/destination")
@SendTo("/topic/someTopic")
public String send(@Header("simpSessionAttributes") Map<String, Object> sessionAttributes) {
    String clientsAddress = sessionAttributes.get("ip"));
    return "The sender's address is: " + clientsAddress ;
}
```

I am not familiar to the origin of the "simpSessionAttributes" name of the header of the message, but I noticed that if I put the information in a way it is described in this thread by the @Sergi Almar - I get such result. But perhaps this name "simpSessionAttributes" may depend on some environment configuration or particular implementation of the message framework idk...

Also I do not mind to include this detalization as a part of the answer of the @Sergi Almar.