# How to add a interceptor to a WebSocket

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, interceptor, spring-websocket

I am using a library on my Spring Boot application and this library is exposing a WebSocket endpoint for the clients to communicate. In my use case, I want to enrich the data this library is sending on the WebSocket. I'm thinking of adding a WebSocket interceptor to capture the data and manipulate it, but I am not sure whether it's possible to add an interceptor to a WebSocket endpoint that is exposed by a third party library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to intercept connection and subscription with Spring Stomp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49756686/how-to-intercept-connection-and-subscription-with-spring-stomp)

Comment: I want to add an inceptor to an endpoint that was exposed by a third party library on my project. The above one doesn’t solve my issue